# Download a large file >100MB from a gRPC server in chunks using gRPC streaming? How can I track which chunk to send next on the server?

Tags: android, grpc, grpc-java, chunking

I am trying to download a large file >100MB from a gRPC server using gRPC bidirectional streaming. I need to break the file into chunks on the server and stream the bytes. I am not sure how to track which chunk the client in asking for in each call? Is there another way to track it rather than sending a chunk number provided the size of chunks is fixed and the chunk number can be calculated?

Current code where I need to add chunk tracking
Proto File -

```
message ReqFilePath { string value = 1; }

message Bytes { bytes value = 1; }

service FileService {
  rpc DownloadFile(ReqFilePath) returns (stream Bytes) {}
}
```

Server implmentation -

```
@Override
    public void downloadFile(ReqFilePath request, StreamObserver<Bytes> responseObserver) {
        File file = new File(request.getValue());
        if (!file.exists()) {
            responseObserver.onError(Status.FAILED.withDescription("file not found!").asRuntimeException());
            return;
        }
        InputStream in;
        try {
            in = new FileInputStream(file);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            responseObserver.onError(Status.INTERNAL.withDescription(ex.getMessage()).asRuntimeException());
            return;
        }
        StreamHandler handler = new StreamHandler(in);
        Exception ex = handler.handle(bytes -> {
            responseObserver.onNext(Bytes.newBuilder().setValue(bytes).build());
        });
        if (ex != null) ex.printStackTrace();

        responseObserver.onCompleted();
    }
```

Comment: Use RandomAccessFile over normal file object since that gives you more compatibility to jump your cursor at any location in your file.

Answer (score 0):

gRPC will already break up the single message into 16KB chunks for sending over the network and then reassemble it on the receiving end.

If you want to break up the bytes yourself and support requesting arbitrary chunks you pretty much have to associate an identifier with each chunk which would be the chunk number.

It sounds like you are asking for a way to implement it as effectively a series of unary calls rather than taking advantage of the stream and just have the server stream down chunks independently of any communication from the client which would avoid the round trip delay of waiting for the client to request a specific chunk. The code you currently have seems to just stream the chunks.  You might want to keep the basic structure of what you have, wrap it in a message that contains both chunk number and the bytes and perhaps add a first chunk argument for restarts.

Comment: Are you saying that if a start a byte stream for a file of size 100MB-1GB gRPC will by default break it down into 16KB chunks and reassemble the file on the client/server?

Comment: As long as you are using Netty (NettyChannelBuilder), that is what is happening.